# Series and Parallel Circiuts

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

Will connecting, 6x1.5v(non recharge) cells (in series) to a 9v battery(non recharge) through parallel combination, increase circuits capacity while keeping the voltage same?

If yes, then will this be true if the 9v battery was rechargeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you should be able to supply the same load with the same voltage (or a little higher) for longer than with a single battery. However it is bad practice to connect batteries in parallel. Even if they have the same nominal e.m.f. (9 V in your case), the emf's won't *stay* exactly equal and the difference in emfs will drive some current through the loop consisting of just the two batteries. This will run one of them down (without doing the other one any good), even when there is no load.

Answer (score -1):

So long as the batteries are of the same type, it should. The 9v battery will consist of 6 cells in series.

Comment: Thanks, but will it be true for rechargeble 9v battery?

Comment: If the batteries are not of the same type, the voltages will not be the same, and nor will the internal resistance of the battery. Depending on the application, they may be near enough, and one battery will discharge first, then the other will kick in.